# In tensorflow 2.0, how to compute gradients of loss to input variables?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow 2.0, tf.gradients is not supported, and GradientTape only compute gradients to trainable weights, so how to get gradients to input as TF1.0 can do?
thanks, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I might have gotten the answer: Just create input tensor, and watch it at the very beginning of the GradientTape context.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already mentioned the answer, providing the explanation and code details below for the community.

For TensorFlow 2 you need to use GradientTape to compute gradients of loss for input.

Here is the explanation of how GradientTape works.

Let's create some sample toy function.

```
def f(w1, w2):
    return 3 * w1 ** 2 + 2 * w1 * w2
```

Define w1, w2, and compute gradients.

```
w1, w2 = tf.Variable(5.), tf.Variable(3.)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    z = f(w1, w2)

gradients = tape.gradient(z, [w1, w2])
```

**Output gradients:**

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=36.0>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=10.0>]
```

Now, let's see how the GradientTape works with `tf.constant` as Input instead of `tf.Variable`.

```
c1, c2 = tf.constant(5.), tf.constant(3.)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    z = f(c1, c2)

gradients = tape.gradient(z, [c1, c2])
```

**Output for gradients will be.**

```
[None, None]
```

By default, the tape will only track operations involving variables, so if
you try to compute the gradient of z with regard to anything other than a
variable, the result will be None.

This will be the same case with inputs also Since the inputs are not variables, you would need to tell the tape to **watch** them.

You can force the tape to watch any tensors you like, to record
every operation that involves them. You can then compute gradients with
regard to these tensors as if they were variables.

**GradientTape with watch:**

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(c1)
    tape.watch(c2)
    z = f(c1, c2)

gradients = tape.gradient(z, [c1, c2])
```

You can see the output gradients now:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=36.0>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=10.0>]
```

Comment: @tim.bob - If you think I have answered your question, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank You.